# When can you apply Ehrenfest's theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I know when the initial state ($\Psi(x,0)$) is given, $\frac{d\langle x\rangle}{dt} \not=$ $\langle p\rangle $. I thought you can only apply [Ehrenfest's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem) when $\Psi$ is a function of $x$ and $t$, however it seems like you can also apply it to the time-independent part ($\psi(x)$) by itself as well. Can someone explain to me why Ehrenfest's theorem is valid for $\psi(x)$?

Comment: [Ehrenfest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem) is valid for any operator.

Comment: So $\Psi(x,0)$ is not an operator but $\psi(x)$ is? How come it doesn't work for $\Psi(x,0)$?

Comment: $\Psi$ is an abstract state vector. Choosing a basis doesn't change it. What are you asking?

Comment: How come you can't apply Ehrenfest's Thrm when you're dealing with $\Psi (x,0)$ and how come you can apply ET when you're dealing with $\psi (x)$?

Comment: Do you know how time evolution / separation of variables works?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean or are getting at, but I think I see my confusion. It looks as if ET is being applied to ψ(x) but I think its just because the time dependent part disappears when you multiply it by its complex conjugate. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, but if you're right, it's an extremely narrow interpretation of a very powerful theorem.